# Unix command line: find different behaviour from dir to dir

Tags: unix, command-line, makefile, find

I'm using a find command in a makefile like so:

```
CC = clang++
CODE = $(shell find . -name *.cpp) #find command here !!!!!!
EXEC = tcr_translator

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(OBJECT)
    clear
    $(CC) $(CODE) -o $(EXEC) -I src/

clean:
    rm $(EXEC)

run: all
    ./tcr_translator
```

So, this find command list all the cpp file to compile, makes it easier than to hard-write them in my makefile. This worked perfectly for my last project, so I took the same makefile for my new project. My problem, now the find command (which is, char for char, the same command) won't look into my subdirectories. 
So if I have .cpp in a src/ subfolder, it won't find them.

Why would such a command work in a certain directory and not in an other. I'm really at a loss here :(

Comment: This is not very useful as a makefile.  You could get identical behavior in one line of shell scripting.  The point of using make is to avoid redoing work that's not necessary; if you just want to recompile everything every time anything changes, you might as well just write a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should quote the `*.cpp` to avoid it from being expanded by shell before passed into `find`.

```
CODE = $(shell find . -name '*.cpp')
```

Comment: wow ok it worked.... any idea why without the quotes it was working on my previous project? Anyhow, thanks a lot... accepting when I can :P

Comment: The difference between your projects is that in your last project you didn't have any `.cpp` files in the top directory, so `*.cpp` didn't match anything and the shell passed it unmolested to `find`.  In this project you have some `.cpp` file in the top directory so it matches and the shell expands it and passes `-name foo.cpp` to `find` instead.